# R - cleaning data with repeated columns for different locations

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, qualtrics

#Edited to make my data more similar to the data I'm working with and example of what I have tried

I am working with a Qualtrics survey where blocks of questions repeat themselves based on previous questions using a function in the survey build called "loop and merge". I'm trying to pull out like questions and then use rbind so that each question only shows up once in a column. I have a basic example below, however in my actual data, the repeats happen 36 times.

example data frame:

```
capacity_1 <- data.frame("1_q1" = 1:4,
                  "1_q2" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                  '1_q3' = 10:13,
                  '1_q4' = 100:103,
                  '1_q5' = 110:113,
                  '1_q6' = 11:14,
                  "2_q1" = 22:25,
                  "2_q2" = c("i", "j", "k", "l"),
                  '2_q3' = 20:23,
                  '2_q4' = 200:203,
                  '2_q5' = 210:213,
                  '2_q6' = 21:24,
                  "3_q1" = 90:93,
                  "3_q2" = c("p", "q", "r", "s"), 
                  '3_q3' = 10:13,
                  '3_q4' = 300:303,
                  '3_q5' = 310:313,
                  '3_q6' = 31:34,check.names = FALSE)
```

note that the "1_" at the start of "1_q1" is the county's reference number

What I could do but that is inefficient, especially since my actual data repeats these questions 36 times:

```
dat_1 <- dat %>%
  select(1:2) %>%
  rename(q = 1:2) %>%
  mutate("county" = 1)
                  
dat_2 <- dat %>%
  select(3:4) %>%
  rename(q = 1:2) %>%
  mutate("county" = 2)

dat_3 <- dat %>%
  select(5:6) %>%
  rename(q = 1:2)%>%
  mutate("county" = 3)

dat_final <- rbind(dat_1, dat_2, dat_3)
```

the "dat_final" data frame is what I'd like the data to look like, but also have formatted again here:

```
dat_clean <- data.frame("q1" = c(1:4, 22:25, 90:93),
                        "q2" = c("a", "b", "c", "d", 
                                 "i", "j", "k", "l", 
                                 "p", "q", "r", "s"),
                        "county" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3))
```

Update - Tried suggestion below, and get the error "error in "set_names()" the size of 'nm' (6) must be compatible with the size of 'x'(2)

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(seq(1,ncol(capacity_1),6), \(i) {
    capacity_1 %>% 
      select(c(i,i+5)) %>% 
      rename_all(~c("capacity_outpatient", "capacity_inpatient", "capacity_housing", 
             "capacity_recovery", "capacity_demand", "capacity_notes")) %>% 
      mutate(county=(i+5)/6)
  })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, which uses a seq from 1 to `ncol(dat)`, by 2:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(seq(1,ncol(dat),2), \(i) {
    dat %>% select(c(i,i+1)) %>% rename_all(~c("q1","q2")) %>% mutate(county=(i+1)/2)
  })
)
```

Output:

```
   q1 q2 county
1   1  a      1
2   2  b      1
3   3  c      1
4   4  d      1
5  22  i      2
6  23  j      2
7  24  k      2
8  25  l      2
9  90  p      3
10 91  q      3
11 92  r      3
12 93  s      3
```

Another approach, with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)

rbindlist(lapply(seq(1,ncol(dat),2), \(i) {
  setnames(dat[,i:(i+1)],c("q1","q2"))
}), use.names=F,idcol = "county")
```

Output:

```
    county q1 q2
 1:      1  1  a
 2:      1  2  b
 3:      1  3  c
 4:      1  4  d
 5:      2 22  i
 6:      2 23  j
 7:      2 24  k
 8:      2 25  l
 9:      3 90  p
10:      3 91  q
11:      3 92  r
12:      3 93  s
```

Comment: Thank you - the do.call option you gave me makes sense, but I'm coming across an error - my real data has 6 columns that repeat (and the df name is "capacity_1").  I've edited the code to take this into account, but am getting the error "Error in 'set_names()' The size of 'nm (6) must be compatible with the size of 'x' (2).  Edited code in follow up comment

Comment: `do.call( rbind, lapply(seq(1,ncol(capacity_1),6), \(i) { capacity_1 %>% select(c(i,i+5)) %>% 
      rename_all(~c("capacity_outpatient", "capacity_inpatient", "capacity_housing", 
             "capacity_recovery", "capacity_demand", "capacity_notes")) %>% 
      mutate(county=(i+5)/6)
  })
)`

Comment: The data.table option worked, except for the county names were wrong

Comment: sorry for the formatting on the code - had trouble editing in the comment box!

Comment: I can probably help, but can't you just edit the actual question, with data that shows your actual data?

Comment: Thanks - I edited to make the data more comparable (the real data set is huge) and included what I've tried more recently

Comment: i think i see the problem.. you are only selecting `i` and `i+5`, which is two columns.. instead you want to `select(i:(i+5))`

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `dplyr, purrr, stringr` - This solution is not affected by columns orders, number of `q` columns. It just use the perfix as base for processing data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

dat <- data.frame("1_q1" = 1:4,
                  "1_q2" = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                  "2_q1" = 22:25,
                  "2_q2" = c("i", "j", "k", "l"),
                  "3_q1" = 90:93,
                  "3_q2" = c("p", "q", "r", "s"), check.names = FALSE)

# Here is the indexes of county that want to extract from df
county_index <- c("1", "2", "3")

# Function that take index as input and will extract data from `dat` df
edit_df <- function(index) {
  dat %>%
    # select column start with index prefix
    select(matches(paste0(index, "_"))) %>%
    # remove the index prefix from string
    rename_all(~ str_replace(., regex("^\\d+_", ignore_case = TRUE), "")) %>%
    # add county column with the input inex
    mutate("county" = as.numeric(index))
}
```

Result using `purrr::map_dfr`

```r
# map the county index that want to extract from original df and edit_df function
dat_clean <- map_dfr(.x = county_index, .f = edit_df)

dat_clean
#>    q1 q2 county
#> 1   1  a      1
#> 2   2  b      1
#> 3   3  c      1
#> 4   4  d      1
#> 5  22  i      2
#> 6  23  j      2
#> 7  24  k      2
#> 8  25  l      2
#> 9  90  p      3
#> 10 91  q      3
#> 11 92  r      3
#> 12 93  s      3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>